# Update gem on staging server only

Tags: ruby, bundler

I want to update one of my gems on staging server ONLY. So, I'm running

```
bundle update gemname
```

or

```
bundle install
```

but then I got error:

```
You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control
```

The problem is that I can't do it locally and I can't push it into git repository. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my problem was specific and quite rare, because I could't deploy app with new features due to situation with my client. Maybe it sounds awful, but at first I got to locally update my Gemfile, run `bundle install`, manually copy Gemfile.lock to my server and after all I could update gems as I want to. It works at now and when I will be allowed to deploy whole app code with capistrano, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups in your `Gemfile` like this in your case:

```
group :staging do
    gem 'gem_name', 'gem_version'
end
```

Only put the gems that you want to use in that specific environment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but creating group is not the solution - in that case I will need to deploy anyways, but as I said, I'm not able to do it now.